# symfony2 neither property nor method exists in class

Tags: forms, symfony

One route on click on button is for this controller:

```
public function addAction(Request $request){
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $spotEntity = $this->getCurrentSpot();
        $permitsidrand = rand(0, 1000000000000);
        $currentDate = new DateTime();
        $permitsrepo = new Permits();


        $permitsrepo->setCreatedat($currentDate);
        $permitsrepo->setPermitid($permitsidrand);
        $permitsrepo->setPermitsSpot($spotEntity);
        $em->persist($permitsrepo);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('permits_add', array('id' => $permitsrepo->getId())));
    }
```

So I want to make new Object and fill it with couple variables and after it I want to redirect to screen with form that will be updating my record from database which I just added.

Here is second function (this one that I am redirecting to after click in button)

```
public function addfullAction(Request $request, $id){

        $permitsidrand = rand(0, 1000000000000);
        $currentDate = new DateTime();
        $permitsrepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MainCoreBundle:Permits');
        $perm= $permitsrepo->find($id);


        $form = $this->createForm(new PermitsType(), $permitsrepo);

        $permitsrepo->setCreatedat($currentDate);
        $permitsrepo->setPermitid($permitsidrand);
        $permitsrepo->setPermitsSpot($spotEntity);

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $form->bind($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

                $em->persist($permitsrepo);
                $em->flush();
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('permits_show'));
            }
        }


        return $this->render('MainAdminBundle:Permits:add.html.twig', $this->getViewConstants(array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'rand' =>$permitsidrand
        )));

    }
```

And when I click that Button that I mantion I have this error message:

```
Neither property "PermitsContractor" nor method "getPermitsContractor()" nor method "isPermitsContractor()" exists in class "Main\CoreBundle\Entity\PermitsRepository"
```

Here is my form

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder->add('PermitsContractor', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'MainCoreBundle:Generalcontractor',
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
            'property'=>'name',
            'label'=> 'Generalny wykonawca',
        ));


        $builder->add('PermitsCompany', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'MainCoreBundle:Company',
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
            'property'=>'name',
            'label'=> 'Firma',
        ));

        $builder->add('Permitname', 'text',array('label'=> "Imię", 'required'=>false));
        $builder->add('Permitsurname', 'text',array('label'=> "Nazwisko", 'required'=>false));

        $builder->add('expirationdate', 'date', array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'label'=> 'Data ważności',
        ));


        $builder->add('file', 'file', array('required'=>false, 'label'=>'Przeglądaj'));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'main_admin_permits_type';
    }
```

I checkout and I got getters and setters in Entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here

```
    $perm = $permitsrepo->find($id);
    $permitsrepo->setCreatedat($currentDate);
    $permitsrepo->setPermitid($permitsidrand);
    $permitsrepo->setPermitsSpot($spotEntity);
```

Use

```
    $perm = $permitsrepo->find($id);
    $perm->setCreatedat($currentDate);
    $perm->setPermitid($permitsidrand);
    $perm->setPermitsSpot($spotEntity);
```